# vue js resolve parent data before child

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I wonder whats the best practice to fetch data between rotues.
I have parent route, which contains a list of items, and child route which renders when selecting an item from the list.

By entering the main route, I fetch the list from vuex store.
By entering the child route, I look for the proper item inside the items list.
The issue is, that the list isnt fetch before the child route is rendered.

Whats the best way to load the parent's data before the child?

Thanks.

Comment: just put a `v-if="!list.length"` on the child, that way the child won't render until the list is full

Comment: Vuejs is bottom up approach, you can use `computed` or bind data using `props`. Share your code or live demo ?